# Is there a way to limit number of total lines OR line breaks in React Native's TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to either limit the number user line breaks, or just simply limit the total number of lines a user can enter in React Native. Does anyone have a solution for this without any flickering or cursor jumping back and forth? Any help or hints would be great.

Basically I'd like to get it to work how 'maxLength' works for number of characters.

The following will jump the cursor ahead. I've also tried preventingDefault onKeyPress=='Enter', which still causes the jumping of the cursor.

```
  handleTextChange(text) {
    let breaks = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length
    if (breaks > 6) {
      return
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: text })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [numberOfLines](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#numberoflines) prop should be what you're looking for. Works in conjunction with `multiline=true`.

Though it does say it's for Android only.

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean but I forgot to include I'm looking for the IOS equivalent of that.